# Python, openpyxl column with adjustment

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, openpyxl

Hopefully someone can help explain a line of code for me in the block blow. I got this from another post but was unable to ask the question using comments because I'm a new user and do not have enough reputation points..

Anyways, Python noob here, please forgive me. How did the poster know `col[0].column` will get the column name? I couldn't find in the openpyxl docs where the `.column` properties came from.

```
for col in worksheet.columns:
     max_length = 0
     column = col[0].column # Get the column name
     for cell in col:
         try: # Necessary to avoid error on empty cells
             if len(str(cell.value)) > max_length:
                 max_length = len(cell.value)
         except:
             pass
     adjusted_width = (max_length + 2) * 1.2
     worksheet.column_dimensions[column].width = adjusted_width
```

Comment: https://linux.die.net/diveintopython/html/power_of_introspection/getattr.html

Comment: *"How did `col[0].column` get the column name?"* The doc says `.column` **Column number of this cell (1-based)**. No *name*, but the index of the given **cell** `col[0]`. E.g. `2` for column `B`.

Answer (score 0):

col[0].column is returning number while worksheet.column_dimensions[column] accepts only character such as 'A', 'B', 'C' in place of column. I've modified the code and it is working fine now.

```
import re

for col in _ws.columns:
max_lenght = 0
print(col[0])
col_name = re.findall('\w\d', str(col[0]))
col_name = col_name[0]
col_name = re.findall('\w', str(col_name))[0]
print(col_name)
for cell in col:
    try:
        if len(str(cell.value)) > max_lenght:
            max_lenght = len(cell.value)
    except:
        pass
adjusted_width = (max_lenght+2)
_ws.column_dimensions[col_name].width = adjusted_width
```